# Change default sort order in ActiveAdmin scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

For most models, the default sort order (id desc) is fine. But for a couple of scopes on one of my models, it would make more sense to reverse the order, or order by the updated_at field.

I seem unable to achieve this without breaking other functionality, so I'm hoping someone else might teach me how to do this!

I've tried adding a .order() on the objects I'm returning:

```
scope :example do |models|
  models.order('id asc')
end
```

This does not seem to have any effect.

I've also tried unscoping, which kind of works. It does sort my objects the way I want to, but it completely breaks all filtering/search functionality.

```
scope :example do |models|
  models.unscoped.order('id asc')
end
```

What to do?

Comment: @beck03076 This comment is not constructive at all. If you don't have the answer to his question, no need to troll.

Comment: @rogerkk https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/312

Comment: Thanks @ahmet, I did not find that issue when googling. I've tried the suggestions there now, and the sort order is still being overridden somehow.

Comment: I'm also noticing that the links my active admin scopes generate on my index page all have order=id_desc in the URL. I have no idea where that stems from, but it does not seem to have any effect removing that part of the URL either.

Answer (score 15):

use config.sort_order like:

```
config.sort_order = "updated_at_desc"
```

Comment: As far as I understand this will change the sort order on all scopes. I want some of them to be sorted differently.

Comment: Not necessarily as it could be Added inside ActiveAdmin registration module. 
```
ActiveAdmin.register Model do
  config.sort_order = 'updated_at_desc'
  ...
end
```

Comment: This drove me a little cray, but the docs are clear (just search "order"): https://activeadmin.info/3-index-pages.html

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  config.sort_order = 'name_asc'
end
```

Answer (score 6):

Why not make 2 scopes in your model, one for a particular sort order, the other, reversed, then in ActiveAdmin set one as the default?

```
scope :example_asc, :default => true
scope :example_desc
```

If that doesn't work for you, perhaps create a controller block in ActiveAdmin that defines what you're trying to do:

```
controller do
  def asc
    Model.order('id ASC')
  end
  def desc
    Model.order('id DESC')
  end
end

scope :example do |models|
  asc
end

scope :example do |models|
  desc
end
```

And finally, I think this answer is probably fairly accurate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17612718/175825

But you might want to investigate more about how you can implement `sort_order`:

- https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/dsl.rb#L25
- https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/dsl.rb#L97

For what it's worth, I'm not a fan of ActiveAdmin's skinny docs. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

This works and also ensures that the default sort order to correctly reflected in the UI.

This is overwriting the `apply_sorting` method of ActiveAdmin, so all the usual caveats about monkey patching third party gems apply.

```
  module ActiveAdmin
    class ResourceController < BaseController
      module CallableSortOrder
        def apply_sorting(chain)
          params[:order] ||= if active_admin_config.sort_order&.respond_to?(:call)
                               active_admin_config.sort_order.call(self)
                             else
                               active_admin_config.sort_order
                             end
          super
        end
      end

      prepend CallableSortOrder
    end
  end
```

Use it like this:

```
  config.sort_order = ->(controller) {
    controller.params[:scope] == 'something' ? 'created_at_desc' : 'name_asc'
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use reorder to override the default order, but also be sensitive as to whether ActiveAdmin sorts are being applied

```
scope :example do |models|
  if params[:order].blank? or params[:order] == "id_desc" #default ordering
    models.example.reorder('your order SQL here')
  else
    models.example
  end
end
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it unfortunately leaves me unable to manually sort by any of the other columns through the UI.

Comment: 18 months later... I have returned to googling this problem and finally have a solution. Updated answer above.

Comment: One downside with this answer is that the UI continues to reflect the default sort order.

Answer (score 1):

@yxf's answer is correct, but I found it unclear ("where does `config` come from?!").

Docs: https://activeadmin.info/3-index-pages.html (just search "order")

Code:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  config.sort_order = 'name_asc'
end
```